# Finding a bigger Frobenius algebra for a given local algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gap

Let $A=K\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle/I$ be a local finite dimensional algebra with admissible relations $I$.

> Question: Is there a canonical way to check whether $A$ is isomorphic to $B/\operatorname{soc}(B)$ for a Frobenius algebra $B$ (and construct the relations of B explicity)? Is there a way to check this with the GAP-package QPA?

If this is the case, then $B$ is local too and the socle must be one-dimensional. Thus $B$ has exactly vector space dimension $\dim A+1$.

Comment: Proper notation is not $A=K<x_1,\ldots,x_n>/I,$ but $A=K\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle/I.$ I edited accordingly and also changed $dim A+1$ to $\dim A+1$. Note that you can enter "latex symbols" into a search engine and find out about things like this.

Comment: @MichaelHardy https://twitter.com/d_m_d_m_d_d/status/1609239167409750016?s=20&t=3eool6vVae-SnicDubugHQ

Comment: @MichaelHardy Why did you leave MSE?